# CSS background image larger than window buggy

Tags: css, positioning

I have a weird issue that's probably more of a bad coding than anything else.

Basically, [I have this site](http://c2io.com/) where if you resize your browser just around the size of the website, you will see that you can scroll right. This is because I have a `<div>` with the `position: absolute` on the right side of the site with a width and height that seems to "push" the website outside of the window and if you scroll, you'll see that the top part of the site don't respect my `width:100%`.

If you understand my explanation, could you tell me what is the right way to code this?

Comment: Can't tell for sure, but it looks like the `margin: 0 auto;` property you have on your `#sbicenter` div is causing the problem. Removing that definitely seems to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i change that, my 2 transparent images on each side disapear... so it doesn't work

Comment: Well, if you really want to code your website the right way, I'm tempted to say just to recode your `#bcktop` div to be more like your site header: a 100% width div, with a fixed-width `position: relative;` div inside that said images can be anchored and positioned relative to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the overflow-x: hidden; to the body id in css

it's a good way to hide that scroll bar and keep those images aside. your body css will look like this

```
body{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image: url(images/bckpattern.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help,this is the quickest way to fix this. I'll try later the other suggestion but this one is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Some defintiion
Viewport= the rectangle of the browser that is showing the page

The reason why your top part "doesnt respect" the width:100%, is because when you absolute position an element its completly removed from the flow. That means that there is no way for div#bcktop to know that there is more content to the right.

When you say "width:100%" on an element whose parent is body, you are saying "Set the width equal to the viewport's"

The answer by rmagnum2002 is the dirty but quick way to fix your problem, as its just hiding the issue. And, what about users who have smaller screens? they wont be able to use that area of the page (im assuming sbi_right will fulfill some use in the future)

Instead, i recomend the following fix
Set the property **min-width** on your horizontal bars so that when the user resizes its browser (or when their screen isnt big enough), those bars will still hold up the entire page.

Here is an example:

```
<div id="annoncetop" style="min-width:MAX_WIDTH_OF_PAGE_CONTENT">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input and explainations. That's what I realized that the viewport 100% was the problem but couldn't find a quick way to fix it. For the 'sbi_right' it's really just a placeholder for the image on the right, same thing for the one on the left. So if the user has a smaller screen size, we don't 'need' to see the image, that's why I don't want to allow scroll. Thanks